# Azure ARM Template Deployment task is not able to download Templates from Storage Account(Configured via Vnet/subnet)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-devops-pipelines

I am using Linked Template to deploy ARM template in Target env, While deploying I am storing the templates in blob contaier using “Azure File Copy” and generating URL and SAS token for the container.

But As my Storage account is configured via VNet/Subnet private endpoint, My A**RM template deployment task** is failing to download the Templates from the storage account.

I am checking for a workaround here, Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), please refer to this doc: [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops) to configure your VNet/Subnet.

If you use private agents in pipeline, it will access to your Storage account via local network, please make sure that the local network can access to your Storage account.

In addition, you need to set up valid [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-azure-resource-manager) when using this [Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template Deployment Task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md).

Comment: I am using Self-Hosted Agent which is configured on the same network, But I think "ARM template deployment" task is via cloud only, so it is not using the agent, It is trying to access the container via cloud only, That's why facing the issue

Comment: It in fact access to your storage account via the ARM service connection, so you need to make sure that this service connection can access to it without network related issues. You could check whether this issue exists locally without using Azure pipeline.

Comment: Hi LoGan, How about this issue? Do you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @Edward, The issue is still not resolved,  I think we can't use storageaccount with private endpoint configuration for linkedtemplate deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems so. You could submit a suggestion ticket about this here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Edward, Ticket already raised about the issue, They doesn't support this feature as of now.  Ticket URL-
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-arm-template-deployment-task-is-not-able-to/1412335?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1419775